# JQuery css condição if cor do texto

Tags: jquery, css

Eu tenho este código. O problema é que está tudo a funcionar bem exceto a cor do texto não mudar.

jQuery:

```
$("#btnContactMob").on("click", function () {
$("#contactMob").stop(true).slideToggle(function () {
    if ($('#contactMob').is(':visible')) {
        $('#btnContactMob').css(
          'background-color', '#FFF',
          'color', '#FFF');
    } else {
        $('#btnContactMob').css('background-color', '#CCCCCC');
    }
 });
```

});

CSS:

```
#btnContactMob {
cursor: pointer;
width: 100%;
height: 55px;
color: #333;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
border-top:1px solid #1a1a1a;
font-family: Lato-Regular;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
font-size: 26px;
}
#contactMob {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
position: relative;
background-color: #FFF;
float: left;
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) aceita uma objeto para mudar várias propriedades ao mesmo tempo. A syntaxe correta é pares `'propriedade': 'valor'`

Exemplo:

```
{   
    'propriedadeCSS_A': 'valor_A',  
    'propriedadeCSS_B': 'valor_B',     
}
```

**Teste assim no seu código:**

```
$('#btnContactMob').css({
      'background-color': '#FFF',
      'color': '#FFF'
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, Faltava os "{}"

Comment: Miguel, ótimo que ficou a funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Sua sintaxe está errada, você deve usar um objeto literal no parametro da função `jQuery.fn.css`, assim você pode passar quantas propriedades precisar.

**Veja um exemplo:**

```
$('#btnContactMob').css({
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    color : '#fff'
});
```

**Você pode conferir a documentação oficial dessa função [clicando aqui](http://api.jquery.com/css/).**